# MySQL FULLTEXT not working properly after a period of time

Tags: mysql, mariadb, full-text-search, innodb

I created a little table table for testing, in which there is the attribute "video_name" with the FULLTEXT modifier:

```
| videos | CREATE TABLE `videos` (
  `video_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `video_name` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`video_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `video_name_2` (`video_name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `video_name` (`video_name`),
  CONSTRAINT `no_empty_name` CHECK (`video_name` <> '')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=153 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
```

With this, I can do searches in both the NATURAL LANGUAGE and BOOLEAN mode.

Sadly, It seems that the modifier It isn't working correctly if I don't use the DB after a period of time.
The first time something went wrong, I noticed that the search was only working with the newer entries, only getting empty results with the older ones, even in BOOLEAN mode searching with the exact value of the "video_name", so the problem isn't because the number of rows. At that moment I fixed it by removing the modifier and applying It once again.

Now, today I was having problems again, but this time the entries that I have just added where the ones not working. Like the last time, re-applying the modifier fixed the problem, but, as we can see, It's pretty much guaranteed that the problems will appear again.

Is this behaviour correct? Am I missing some configuration?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:

This is what the command `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_ft%'` returns:

```
+---------------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name                   | Value      |
+---------------------------------+------------+
| innodb_ft_aux_table             |            |
| innodb_ft_cache_size            | 8000000    |
| innodb_ft_enable_diag_print     | OFF        |
| innodb_ft_enable_stopword       | ON         |
| innodb_ft_max_token_size        | 84         |
| innodb_ft_min_token_size        | 3          |
| innodb_ft_num_word_optimize     | 2000       |
| innodb_ft_result_cache_limit    | 2000000000 |
| innodb_ft_server_stopword_table |            |
| innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree       | 2          |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size      | 640000000  |
| innodb_ft_user_stopword_table   |            |
+---------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: I suspect that FULLTEXT isn't terribly useful against such tiny strings.

Comment: try to reidex, but i also don't see why the overhead

Comment: What version of mysql/mariadb?  How many rows in the table?  Are the `video_names` single words, or multiple words?  Are there only a few dozen rows?  Does the query include "short" words?  Let's see an example.  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_ft%';`

Comment: Hi.

My mysql/mariadb is 10.3.25.

The table has 7 rows.

video_names can have multiple words.
That command result I will add it to the original post.